# Ubuntu server 14.04.1 not installing to hdd

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation, hard-drive

im am trying to install ubnutu server 14.04.1 to the main hdd in a computer  from a flashdrive, in the installer i select the hdd as the install location but instead it wipes my flash drive and install to it instead

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is the bootloader gets installed on the USB by default.

This is how I fixed this problem on my machine:

Re-install server 14.04.1 on your USB stick like you're doing a clean install.

Boot to USB and select Fix A Broken System.

Go through the prompts.

Select Re-install Bootloader and enter /dev/sda for location.

Select Reboot system.

Hope this helps!